# Loading a property file by reading line by line from another file

Tags: java, properties

I am reading a file called abc.txt and each line of abc.txt is an properties file. For eg:-

```
label.properties
label_ch.properties
label_da.properties
label_de.properties
label_en.properties
```

So after reading each line I am getting properties file in String line, and after that I am trying to load that properties file but it is not getting loaded. Any thing wrong with my implementation?

**This is my code-**

```
package testing.project;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Properties;

public class Project {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    BufferedReader br = null;
    HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\apps\\apache\\tomcat7\\webapps\\examples\\WEB-INF\\classes\\abc.txt"));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = br.readLine();
        loadProperties(line);

        while (br.readLine() != null) {
            sb.append(line);
            sb.append("\n");
            line = br.readLine();
        }
        String everything = sb.toString();
        System.out.println(everything);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
     catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



    }

    private static void loadProperties(String line) {
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        InputStream in = Project.class.getResourceAsStream(line);
        try {
//As soon as it gets into prop.load(in), cursor goes to br.close that is in main method.
                prop.load(in);
                for(Object str: prop.keySet()) {
                    Object value = prop.getProperty((String) str);
                    System.out.println(str+" - "+value);
                }
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }

    }
```

I am getting error as-

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Properties.load0(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Going through your code it appears all is good except for the ones mentioned above as well.
Instead of writing

```
    String line = br.readLine();
    loadProperties(line);

    while (br.readLine() != null) {
        sb.append(line);
        sb.append("\n");
        line = br.readLine();
    }
```

prefer to write

```
String line = null;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) 
{
    loadProperties(line);
    sb.append(line);
    sb.append("\n");
    line = br.readLine();
}
```

Moreover, since it's a java code, so prefer to put forward slash (/) instead of two backslashes(\), while describing a path to a file.

For Example :

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/Apache/tomcat/webapps/GaganIsOnline/WEB-INF/classes/names.txt"));
```

And please do check, if the file path is proper, mean to say, does the said file abc.txt do exists in that given location.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: If you're getting a `NullPointerException` within `prop.load(in)`, it's possible that

```
Project.class.getResourceAsStream(line)
```

is returning null. You should check for that (and also close the input stream in a finally block). Are you sure `label.properties` is actually present and available to the class loader? How are you running this code? If you're using Eclipse or something similar, you may have forgotten to tell it that your `label.properties` file is a resource which should be copied to the output directory.

---

Well here's one problem:

```
while (br.readLine() != null) {
    sb.append(line);
    sb.append("\n");
    line = br.readLine();
}
```

That's going to skip every other line. Typically I'd use:

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(line);
    sb.append("\n");
}
```

Note that only the *first* line of your file is being used to load a properties file - the rest is just dumped to `System.out`. Also, the properties file you *are* loading is then being thrown away - you don't do anything with `prop` afterwards. (And you should close `in` in a `finally` block, assuming it's non-null.)

Comment: I did that as but still I am getting error as `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Properties.load0(Unknown Source)`

Comment: But it should get loaded in loadProperties method right? As I am looping through the keySet?

Comment: @RaihanJamal: See my edit - I've put it at the top of the answer now. Basically I believe it can't find your file.

Comment: Got it. I forgot to put the whole path where each properties file. So in my case each property file is in this directory.
`InputStream in = Project.class.getResourceAsStream("C:\\apps\\apache\\tomcat7\\webapps\\examples\\WEB-INF\\classes\\"+line);` So it should be written this way? As if I write this way then still I am getting nullpointer exception

Answer (score 1):

Once you fixed the bug mentioned above. Here is the solution to the problem:

```
enum PathType {RESOURCE, ABSOLUTE}

private static void loadProperties(String line, PathType pathType) {
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    InputStream in = null;
    if (pathType == PathType.RESOURCE)
        in = PropertyTest.class.getResourceAsStream(line);
    else {
        try {
            in = new FileInputStream(line);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }
    }

    try {
//As soon as it gets into prop.load(in), cursor goes to br.close that is in main method.
        prop.load(in);
        for (Object str : prop.keySet()) {
            Object value = prop.getProperty((String) str);
            System.out.println(str + " - " + value);
        }
        in.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Code to call it. There are various ways.

- If you want to load properties from base of the class loader. For example, if I am running my application with `main` function from eclipse, my base will be `<some_path>/classes`. So the file `label.properties` is residing there. Also if you are running from Tomcat and `label.properties` lies in `<your_web_app>/classes`. Use the code below:

  `loadProperties("/" + line, PathType.RESOURCE); // Load from base path of class loader`
- If you want to load properties from package folder of the class loader. For example, if I am running my application with `main` function from eclipse, my base will be `<some_path>/classes`. The file `label.properties` is residing in `<some_path>/classes/testing/project`. Also if you are running from Tomcat and `label.properties` lies in `<your_web_app>/classes/testing/project` use below code:

  `loadProperties(line, PathType.RESOURCE); // Load from base path of class loader + the package path`
- If you want load properties from any absolute path on your hard drive. Use below code:

  `loadProperties("C:\\apps\\apache\\tomcat7\\webapps\\examples\\WEB-INF\\classes\\" + line, PathType.ABSOLUTE);`

NOTE: Please handle the exception as per your needs. I just updated your code AS IS.

Answer (score 0):

Method `br.readLine()` is called twice in your code.

```
 while (line != null) {
   loadProperties(line);
   sb.append(line);
   sb.append("\n");
   line = br.readLine();
 }
```

Comment: I did that as but still I am getting error as `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Properties.load0(Unknown Source)`

Comment: @RaihanJamal - What is the location of  .properties files?

Comment: location is this- `InputStream in = NiharikaProject.class.getResourceAsStream("C:\\apps\\apache\\tomcat7\\webapps\\examples\\WEB-INF\\classes\\"+line);` So it should be written this way or some other way?

Comment: Move .properties files into package folder - testing.project (WEB-INF/classes/testing/project)

Comment: Is it possible to load the file from external directory?

Comment: Yes! In this case you have to provide absolute path of file and you have to use FileInputStream class. e.g C:\\apps\\apache\\tomcat7\\webapps\\exampl‌​es\\WEB-INF\\classes\\label.properties".