# Maven does not see some text files I'm using within my unit tests

Tags: java, maven, junit, pom.xml

I'm getting my feet wet with maven, but it's a steep learning curve. I'm trying to load plain text files from within a unit test. The tests passed, now I've converted the project to a maven project, the tests cannot seem to resolve where the test files are.

---

```
// I have the following test that I would like to run:

package net.stevenpeterson.base;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import net.stevenpeterson.base.LoadStringUtility;

import org.junit.Test;

public class LoadStringUtilityTest {

    @Test
    public void testSingleLine() {
        assertEquals("Loading File", "This is a test." , loadFile("singleLine") );
    }

    @Test
    public void testSeveralLines() {
        assertFalse("Compare a string appended with extra lines, should not compare true. ", "This is a test.".equals(loadFile("severalLines")) );
    }

    @Test
    public void loadSherlockHolmes() {
        String fileToLoad = "cano.txt";
        try{
        StringBuilder holmesCanon = LoadStringUtility.LoadString(fileToLoad);

        System.out.println("Finished Loading file: chars read=" + holmesCanon.length());
        assertTrue("loading size of file:", true);
        }catch(Exception e){
         fail("Exception thrown while loading: " + fileToLoad);
        }

    }


    private String loadFile(String fileName) {
        StringBuilder loadedFromFile = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            loadedFromFile = LoadStringUtility.LoadString(fileName);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            fail("Unable to find load file: " + fileName);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return loadedFromFile.toString();
    }
}
```

---

The following is my pom.xml file:

---

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

      <groupId>net.stevenpeterson</groupId>
      <artifactId>bookreader</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <packaging>jar</packaging>

      <name>bookreader</name>
      <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

      <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
      </properties>

      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          <version>4.8.1</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>

    <build>
        <testResources>
          <testResource>
            <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
          </testResource>
        </testResources>
    </build>

    </project>
```

---

When I run unit tests:

---

```
steven@steven-desktop:~/maven-conversion/bookreader$ mvn test
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building bookreader 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3:resources (default-resources) @ bookreader ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/steven/maven-conversion/bookreader/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ bookreader ---
[INFO] Compiling 3 source files to /home/steven/maven-conversion/bookreader/target/classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3:testResources (default-testResources) @ bookreader ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 4 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ bookreader ---
[INFO] Compiling 5 source files to /home/steven/maven-conversion/bookreader/target/test-classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.7.2:test (default-test) @ bookreader ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: /home/steven/maven-conversion/bookreader/target/surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running net.stevenpeterson.base.LoadStringUtilityTest
Tests run: 3, Failures: 3, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.041 sec <<< FAILURE!
Running net.stevenpeterson.base.SplitStringUtilityTest
Tests run: 5, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.004 sec
Running net.stevenpeterson.booksplitter.BookSplitterTest
Tests run: 4, Failures: 4, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.007 sec <<< FAILURE!

Results :

Failed tests: 
  testSingleLine(net.stevenpeterson.base.LoadStringUtilityTest): Unable to find load file: singleLine
  testSeveralLines(net.stevenpeterson.base.LoadStringUtilityTest): Unable to find load file: severalLines
  loadSherlockHolmes(net.stevenpeterson.base.LoadStringUtilityTest): Exception thrown while loading: cano.txt
  ThirdLineOfAlphabetTest(net.stevenpeterson.booksplitter.BookSplitterTest): IOException thrown while loading test file.
  OutOfRangeLineOfAlphabetTest(net.stevenpeterson.booksplitter.BookSplitterTest): IOException thrown while loading test file.
  SectionSizeTwoAlphabetTest(net.stevenpeterson.booksplitter.BookSplitterTest): IOException thrown while loading test file.
  LastLineOfAlphabetTest(net.stevenpeterson.booksplitter.BookSplitterTest): IOException thrown while loading test file.

>     Tests run: 12, Failures: 7, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
>     
>     [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>     [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
>     [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>     [INFO] Total time: 1.634s
>     [INFO] Finished at: Tue Nov 29 19:41:59 MST 2011
>     [INFO] Final Memory: 15M/105M
>     [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>     [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.7.2:test
> (default-test) on project bookreader: There are test failures.
>     [ERROR] 
>     [ERROR] Please refer to /home/steven/maven-conversion/bookreader/target/surefire-reports for
> the individual test results.
>     [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
>     [ERROR] 
>     [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
>     [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
>     [ERROR] 
>     [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
>     [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException


Contents of: /home/steven/maven-conversion/bookreader/target/test-classes
AlphabetTest  cano.txt  net/  severalLines  singleLine

It looks as if Maven is placing the resources in the correct location, I think I'm confused about the relative path that is being used when I execute my tests.
```

Comment: Sometimes, I face same problem with a few open-source Java-based projects that use Maven and include unit tests with test files located in different packages/folders. So, the quick and dirty approach I use to solve the issue is to include the full path of the package/folder of each test file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I usually put my test related plain-text files in the src/test/resources directory under the given project (along with the src/test/java unit tests) which is the default directory for testing resource files... it looks like you are probably doing this from looking at your pom.xml file.  By the way, since it is the default location, you probably don't need to call it out.

From the unit tests you are able to load those files using the classloader:

```
InputStream is = SomeClass.class.getResourceAsStream("cano.txt";);
```

It seems like your issue may be in your LoadStringUtility class.  Without knowing what your LoadStringUtility looks like, I can't give you any direction on what may be wrong.

Looks like you are loading a stream into a String though.  Typically I would use the Apache Commons IO [IOUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html) helper class to pull the input stream contents into a String:

```
String output = IOUtils.toString(is);
```

which could result in a LoadStringUtility that would look like this:

```
public class LoadStringUtility {

    public static String loadStringFromFile(String file) throws IOException {
        InputStream inputStream = LoadStringUtility.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(file);
        return IOUtils.toString(inputStream);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice answer.  Is a leading "/" needed on the resource or is root implied?

Comment: getResourceAsStream() returns resources from the classpath, the root is implied and you should not add a leading slash.

Comment: Not sure what you are showing me with that comment, can you clarify?

Comment: if you're relying on the @Before in a static utility class, it may not be triggered by Maven's Surefire plugin.  You may have to do what I suggested in my response above to get the expected file output.

Comment: I was trying to post my answer, I'm very new to this site. Not into the whole forum thing until recently. My ignorance is astounding. ;) But thanks largely to the answers posted above I came to the solution that I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to help.  Since you're new to the site, if someone helps you and has a answer that is 'correct' it is customary to accept the answer by selecting the green check by the vote toggle.

Comment: I will test the various suggestions, and will follow through.

Answer (score 0):

BTW you dont need to specify the `src/test/resources` to the `build` as it is by default the case.

Pls confirm that `<your_app_base_path>/target/test-classes`.

I dont know how you are loading but you can refer to my reply at [Loading a property file by reading line by line from another file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8207855/loading-a-property-file-by-reading-line-by-line-from-another-file/8208300#8208300)

I am updating here for easy access as well as with some fixes:

```
package testing.project;

import java.io.*;

enum PathType {RESOURCE, ABSOLUTE}

private static InputStream createInputStream(String line, PathType pathType) {
    InputStream in = null;
    if (pathType == PathType.RESOURCE)
        in = PropertyTest.class.getResourceAsStream(line);
    else {
        try {
            in = new FileInputStream(line);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return in;
}
```

Code to call it. There are various ways.

- If you want to load properties from base of the class loader. For example, if I am running my application with `main` function from eclipse, my base will be `<some_path>/classes`. So the file `label.properties` is residing there. Also if you are running from Tomcat and `label.properties` lies in `<your_web_app>/classes`. In maven if running test cases it will be in `<app_base_path>/target/test-classes` else `<app_base_path>/target/classes`. use below code:

  `createInputStream("/" + line, PathType.RESOURCE); // Load from base path of class loader`
- If you want to load properties from package folder of the class loader. For example, if I am running my application with `main` function from eclipse, my base will be `<some_path>/classes`. The file `label.properties` is residing in `<some_path>/classes/testing/project`. Also if you are running from Tomcat and `label.properties` lies in `<your_web_app>/classes/testing/project`, use below code:

  `createInputStream(line, PathType.RESOURCE); // Load from base path of class loader + the package path`
- If you want load properties from any absolute path on your hard drive. Use below code:

  `createInputStream("C:\\apps\\apache\\tomcat7\\webapps\\examples\\WEB-INF\\classes\\" + line, PathType.ABSOLUTE);`

NOTE: Pls handle the exception as per your need. Also modify it as per your need or if I missed some imports. Maven will behave same for last two cases as mentioned in first, just use common sense.

Answer (score 0):

For this case, for better or for worse, all I'm looking for is the path to a specific resource. The information, in the answers given helped me throw together the following:
    package net.stevenpeterson.bookreaderlib;

```
import java.net.URL;

public class ResourceLookup {

    private ResourceLookup(){
    }

    public static String getPathForResource(String name){
        ResourceLookup lookupInstance = new ResourceLookup();
        URL aURL = lookupInstance.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(name);
        return aURL.getPath();
    }
}
```

Following that, I modified the test class:

```
package net.stevenpeterson.bookreaderlib;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;    

import net.stevenpeterson.bookreaderlib.LoadStringUtility;
import net.stevenpeterson.bookreaderlib.ResourceLookup;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

public class LoadStringUtilityTest {


    private String singleLine;
    private String severalLines;
    private String cano;



    @Test 
    public void testGetURLMethod(){
        String resourcePath = ResourceLookup.getPathForResource("singleLine");
        assertNotNull("URL to singleLine should not be null", resourcePath);
    }

    @Test
    public void testSingleLine() {
        assertEquals("Loading File", "This is a test." , loadFile(singleLine) );
    }

    @Test
    public void testSeveralLines() {
        assertFalse("Compare a string appended with extra lines, should not compare true. ", "This is a test.".equals(loadFile(severalLines)) );
    }

    @Test
    public void loadSherlockHolmes() {
        String fileToLoad = this.cano;
        try{
        StringBuilder holmesCanon = LoadStringUtility.LoadString(fileToLoad);
        System.out.println("Finished Loading file: chars read=" + holmesCanon.length());
        assertTrue("loading size of file:", true);
        }catch(Exception e){
         fail("Exception thrown while loading: " + fileToLoad);
        }

    }


    private String loadFile(String fileName) {
        StringBuilder loadedFromFile = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            loadedFromFile = LoadStringUtility.LoadString(fileName);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            fail("Unable to find load file: " + fileName);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return loadedFromFile.toString();
    }


    @Before
    public void loadAllResources(){
        **this.singleLine = ResourceLookup.getPathForResource("singleLine");
        this.severalLines = ResourceLookup.getPathForResource("severalLines");
        this.cano = ResourceLookup.getPathForResource("cano.txt");**
    }
}
```

Comment: which system have you tested this, Windows or Unix flavor?

Comment: Unix, but I do not construct paths, so I believe that the code is portable.

Comment: i thought so, i tried it on windows and i got paths like "/C:\somepath"...(i forgot whether it was / or \ slash). I didnt get a chance to look deeper into it...bt like to share the observation...